# Iterated Integral and Harmonic Mean

Tags: integration

I'm looking at the following iterated integral:
$$
\int_0^\infty\int_0^u tp(t)\ q(u)\ dt du\,
$$
where $0 \leq p(t) \leq 1$ and $0 \leq q(u) \leq 1$. Can an upper bound for the integral above be expressed in terms of $A$ and $B$ where
$$
A = \int_0^\infty tp(t)dt\,
$$
$$
B = \int_0^\infty uq(u)du\,
$$
If we only know $A$ and $B$, under what conditions would the double integral above be equal to (or close to in some sense) to the harmonic mean of $A$ and $B$? Many thanks for your help!